# How to start services in early stage of beaglebone boot?

Tags: splash-screen, beagleboneblack

I am trying to change the Beaglebone black splash screen. 
I am using Angstrom-Cloud9-IDE-GNOME-eglibc-ipk-v2012.12-beaglebone-2013.06.20.img.xz image.

I compiled the psplash source (as explained in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/beagleboard/HRDjAtsPO68/dc7gIZTynQkJ) and now psplash works fine.

In order to automatically start psplash I create a new system service called psplash.service and I enabled it with the command "*systemctl enable psplash.service*".

The problem is: when Beaglebone boots, the psplash is launched a little bit late and you can see for several 
seconds the standard beaglebone logo. How can I configure the service in order to run the psplash as soon as possible ?

Is there a better way than the system services for starting psplash program ?
Here is the system service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Splash screen

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/root/
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/psplash
SyslogIdentifier=psplash

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

Systemd services by default have dependencies so removing the dependencies will allow it to start the service early.

```
[Unit]
Description=Splash screen
DefaultDependencies=no

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/psplash

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

This will cause it to start before other dependencies. You may add dependencies within the [Unit] block with `After=...` or `Before=...`. But be careful with the `Before=...` as it will wait for psplash to end and since psplash will run uninterrupted on its own it may cause start-up to hang.

This will cause the service to run earlier in the systemd process but I am still looking into other ways to get it to start even earlier.

Comment: check out the bootup man page for a nice chart showing some of the standard boot synchronization points (targets)